Is it ok to trigger a popup to fetch information from an input field?
I have this UI where all the fields are inputs.
But two informations need to be fetched by selecting options from a popup.
currently I have the labels and an edit/add icon to triggers and popup. The info fetched will be then shown as Text.
I'm planing to remove the edit/add icons and trigger the popup by placing input fields and show the result in the input field thereafter. Is this UX and UI fine or should I keep how it was before.

I think your intended change is actually needed in order to have consistency between the fields. The less a user has to guess the UI, the better, and users expect to click on fields in order to interact with them. Icon buttons are not that common and they might be seen as optional or be completely missed.
So yes, you should replace them with fields.
And there are a few things to remember:

The field should have a very specific icon suggesting that it will open a popup, usually an arrow, but you might want a different one in order to avoid being confused with a basic select field.

The field should be big enough to accommodate the selection, so try to estimate the size of data that a user might select, because layout shifts are quite annoying and having the right size also helps the user understand what type of input is expected.

Forms with a single column are easier to complete, so if you want to make sure your user will fill all the needed information, place your fields on a single column and leave enough empty space between labels, fields and especially headers.



Thanks Moroco for the feedback. Much appreciated.
